# multiple setOnClickListeners for a single process

Tags: android

In my App I have a line showing an `(ImageButton)icon` and a `(textView)title` of an audio file to play and I use the setOnClickListener for an ImageButton to initiate a process that plays the file. I would also like to use the `(textView)title` as a clickable item to begin the same process.

I could simply duplicate all of the functionality in both setOnClickListeners but that does not seem to be the most efficient way to do it.

Now I am new so is there such a thing as

```
ImageButton.setOnClickListener() ||  textView.setOnClickListener() {

.

.

.

}
```

Basically if the ImageButton is clicked or the textView is clicked do this procedure.

I know the above syntax is not correct but it gives you an idea of what I want to do

Answer (score 3):

Have the `class` that has both these elements `ImageButton` and `textView` implement the `OnClickListener`. `OnClickListener` is an interface that has the method `onClick(View v)` which will have the click implementation for both these elements. Then you can use `imageButton.setOnClickListener(this)` and `textView.setOnClickListener(this)`.

Example Code:

```
public MyClass extends Activity implements  OnClickListener {

ImageButton imageButton;
TextView textView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);

    imageButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    textView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int viewId = v.getId() ;
    if(viewId == R.id.btn || viewId == R.id.txt){
        //common implementation of click event
    }
}
}
```

Hope this explanation helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
    ImageButton iv=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagebutton1);
    TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    iv.setOnClickListener(OnClick);
    tv.setOnClickListener(OnClick);
```

add this in **OnCreate()** method and after that add this method as shown below

```
   private OnClickListener OnClick=new OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(v.getId()){
                         case R.id.imagebutton1:{
                             // do here code what u want on imagebutton click
                                break;}
                         case R.id.textview1:{
                            // do here code what u want on textview click
                               break;}

                }
            }
        }

     };
```

Answer (score 0):

Put both the imagebutton and textview in a layout and give it an ID. Then implement the onClickListener for the layout, by this way you need to write the code only once.

Comment: Thank you I am trying to implement this but am having some issues. I have a linerlayout with a image button and a textview inside. I have created the onclicklistener for the image button but need to move it to the linerlayout so it incorporates the textview as well.  However when I try to add the standard @+id/Audio1 in my XML file it does seem to show up in the findv

Comment: However when I try to add the standard @+id/Audio1 in my XML file it does not seem to show up in the findViewByid(R.id.Audio1) When I type it in manually I get wo quick fix about creating a field or constant Audio1 in id but neither seem to work and do what I am hoping.

Comment: I have also tried adding and ids.xml and add the new id in this way but things got corrupted realy fast and I lost r.java leaving me with so many errors I could not back out of I had to start over.    WHAT Am I Missing